# Dividing lines breaking for a dice roll table

Tags: tables

I am attempting to create a nice table for rolling a six-sided die. The table needs to display the results of the dice roll in the cell below the roll. However, having a newline or even just a large amount of text seems to break the dividing lines.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5cm}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{C|C|C}
    \textbf{1} & \textbf{2-5} & \textbf{6}\\ 
    \hline \\
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{L|L|L}
    Here is some text & Here is some\newline Text with a newline & Here is some text \\ 
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, is there some better package to use for these tables? I'd like to make this table's cells gray in color, to standout more from the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to insert the header and body of the table in separate `tabular`s. Join the two, which will remove the issue of inserting blank cells and use a simplified `\multicolumn{1}{c|}` for each header item:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{5cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ L | L | L }
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{1}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{2-5}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{6}} \\
  \hline
  Here is some text & 
    Here is some \newline
    Text with a newline &
    Here is some text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Tex. For future question please alos provide a full MWE including \documentclass{} and your preamble so that others do not have to guess which package you are loading.

Regarding your question: Should it look like this: (I think I don´t quite understand the newline problem. Do you want the cells have a defined width?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{
            >{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}m{3 cm} |
            >{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}m{3 cm} |
            >{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}m{3 cm} }
                \centering 1         & \centering 2-5              &   \centering 6  \tabularnewline  \hline
          Here is some text & Here is some Text here is more text & Here is some text            
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]